# Plot line-chart on the left axis uper the bar-chart on the right axis

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

In a graph with two y axis, one for a line plot (left) and one for a bar-chart (right), I would like that the bar-chart get under the line chart for a better visibility instead of uper it.

[image: Evolution bar-chart line-plot]

As you can see on this picture (I hope you can see it), the bar chart shows the evolution of the precipitation and the different line the evolution of the chlorophyll index, my problem is that the bar-chart overlay the lines and I want the line to be uper.

This is my script:

```
figure
yyaxis right
bar (meteo(:,1),meteo(:,14));
ylabel('Precipitation (mm)');
hold on
for i=1:6;
    a = [];
    b = [];
    color = ['r' 'm' 'b' 'c' 'g' 'y'];
    for j=0:6
        a(i,j+1)=matrice_5(j*6+i,1);%jour
        b(i,j+1)=matrice_5(j*6+i,3);%moyenne       
    end
        hold on
        yyaxis left
        plot(a(i,:),b(i,:),color(i),'LineWidth',1.5);  
end
title('Evolution of the mean of the chlorophyll index (HNT) - Charlotte variety');
xlabel('Day (2013)')
ylabel('Chlorophyll index (HNT)')
axis([735390 735442 32 50]);
set(gcf,'Position',[645 206 701 477]);
datetick('x','dd mmm','keepticks')
h=legend('0','50','100','150','200','250','precipitation','Location','best');
v = get(h,'title');
set(v,'string','Nitrogen rate in kg/ha');
set(h,'Position', [0.1793 0.1494 0.1127 0.2446]);
hold on
plot([735422 735422],[32 49],'Color',[.3 .3 .3]);
hold off
```

Until now I only got half of the result. I want to put the bar-chart on the left axis (y-axis left) and the line plot on the right axis. I want to keep the Chlorophyll index on the left.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a really great question because there is really no *clearly documented* way of doing this and in all examples, whatever is on the right axes is displayed on top. Even in this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/overlay-line-plot-on-bar-graph-using-different-y-axes-1.html) on their own website, notice how careful they are to plot the `bar` on the left axes.

So as a preface, `yyaxis` does not create a separate axes (as `yyplot` used to), but [rather just applies an additional `NumericRuler` to the *same* axes](http://blogs.mathworks.com/graphics/2016/04/04/yyaxis/). If it were simply different `axes` we could use `uistack` to re-order the axes in any way we want, but because they are the *same* `axes`, we need to look a little closer at the `axes` properties which control the z-ordering of the contents.

When we look at these properties, `yyaxis` automatically changes the `SortMethod` of the axes to `children` from it's default value of `depth`. This makes any object which appears in the left axes to be below anything added to the right axes. So all we need to do to fix this, is to change the `SortMethod` back to the default value (`depth`) and then the ordering will be dependent upon z position like it normally would within an `axes`.

So as a demonstration, let's create some data

```
days = 0:5:35;
conc = [515 420 370 250 135 120 60 20];
temp = [29 23 27 25 20 23 23 17];
```

Create the plots just like you did (a line and a bar with the bar on the right)

```
yyaxis right
b = bar(days, temp, 'FaceColor', [0.8 0.8 0.8]);
yyaxis left
p = plot(days, conc, 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]

And now if we change the `SortMethod` it brings the line object on top.

```
set(gca, 'SortMethod', 'depth')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did like you suggest and it almost do the work. As you can see on the picture of my question, each bar of the chart are encircled in black. So when I apply your code    set(gca, 'SortMethod', 'depth'). 
The line of the plot go uper the font size of the bar chart but not uper those black bar borders. Any idea why ? 
Btw: how can you take out the axes like you did on your graph? And not have border on your bar chart?

Answer (score 5):

This was very helpful. Just to provide more examples, in case of two line plots, you'll need to explicitly specify `ZData` property to control the stack order.

```matlab
days = 0:5:35;
conc = [515 420 370 250 135 120 60 20];

figure

yyaxis left
p1 = plot(days, conc, 'LineWidth', 4);

yyaxis right
p2 = plot(days, fliplr(conc), 'LineWidth', 4);

% orange is on top
```

[image: orange is on top]

```matlab
get(gca,'SortMethod')
set(gca, 'SortMethod', 'depth')

% orange is still on top
```

[image: orange is on top]

```matlab
p1.ZData = ones(size(p1.XData));
p2.ZData = zeros(size(p2.XData));

% blue is on top
```

[image: blue is on top]

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping @Kouichi C. Nakamura's excellent answer up in a convenient function that applies this to all lines of an axis, gets:

```
function ax = setZData(ax,val)
    ax = arrayfun(@(x)setZData_ax(x,val),ax);

    function ax = setZData_ax(ax,val)
        ax.ZData = val*ones(size(ax.XData));
    end
end
```

Or a complete wrapper

```
function varargout = plotLeftOverRitht(LR,varargin)
% wrapper to plot the left axis of dual-axis plot over the right axis

%% process input
% input string
if strcmpi(LR,'left')
    LR = 'left';
    val = 1;
elseif strcmpi(LR,'right')
    LR = 'right';
    val = 0;
else
    error('plotLeftOverRitht:Input:LR',"The first input must be either 'left' or 'right'.")
end

% input: axis handle?
if isa(varargin{1},'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes')
    ax = varargin{1};
    varargin = varargin(2:end);
else
    ax = gca;
end

%% main function
% activate left axis
yyaxis( ax, LR);
% call plot
lines = plot(   ax, varargin{:});
% set height
setZData(lines,val);
% set sorting order
set(ax, 'SortMethod', 'depth')

%% output
if nargout > 0
    varargout = ax;
end
end
```

This changes example above to be

```
days = 0:5:35;
conc = [515 420 370 250 135 120 60 20];

figure
plotLeftOverRitht('left', days,conc, 'LineWidth',4)
plotLeftOverRitht('right', days,fliplr(conc), 'LineWidth',4)
```